# Fast and light JavaScript SHA-256 secure hash implementation

Tags: javascript, security, browser, sha, sha256

I'm looking for a hash implementation that is;

- secure (practically impossible to invert)
- fast (few ms)
- light (few KB)
- runs in the browser

Ideally a SHA-256 implementation, since it is widely used and therefore widely tested against.

Comment: Google `SHA-256 javascript` brings up a number of the popular ones.

Comment: how do you define "fast" vs not fast, or "compact" vs not compact?

Comment: @Xotic750 this is actually more of a wiki answer, see my answer

Comment: @JaromandaX fast: Computationally efficient, e.g. an implementation returning the secure hash within 5ms would be fast. Compact: few KB, e.g. an implementation of 10KB size would be compact

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: @Xotic750: my experience so far is that vague requirements are the problem. But the requirements are very specific and objective here. I don't see any possibility to be subjective and opinionated to such a question.

Comment: you say you want to get a hash within 5ms? What size data? 1kb? 1TB?

Comment: @JaromandaX it was just an example but to make it more concrete: I would consider 5ms for 100KB to be fast. The implementation would ideally scale nicely and be linear with the text size that is to be hashed.

Comment: the clearer the information in the question, the more likely you'll get a clear answer :p

Comment: @JaromandaX true :D. How would you express the question?

Comment: I'd quantify fast and compact, just like you have now :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some [tests](https://github.com/brillout/test-secure-hash-algos) suggests that [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) is the fastest SHA-256 JavaScript implementation.

It is 284KB big but extracting the SHA-256 related code reduces the size to 4.5 KB, see https://github.com/brillout/forge-sha256.

Comment: `Doing some tests suggests that forge is the fastest SHA-256 JavaScript implementation.` What tests did you independently perform?

Comment: @Xotic750: https://github.com/brillout/test-secure-hash-algos/blob/master/main.js

Comment: 2018 answer: Bichlmeier SHA256 seems to be 2X as fast as forge