# jsSHA512 different hashes from same string

Tags: javascript, hash

I'm using the [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA) library to hash passwords but I'm getting different hashes, from the same string, everytime I run the script:

```
/* Password hash function */
var b = $("form#register"),
    shaObj  = new jsSHA('SHA-512', 'TEXT');

b.on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var p = $('#reg_pwd'),
        q = $('#confirm_pwd');

    shaObj.update(p.val());
    var p_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
    //p.val(p_hash);

    shaObj.update(q.val());
    var q_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
    //q.val(q_hash);

    $('p').html('String: ' + p.val() + '<br />Hash: ' + p_hash +
                '<br />String: ' + q.val() + '<br />Hash: ' + q_hash)

    //this.submit()

});
```

I've been able to reproduce this in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pa9sgx3v/3/). Just type any text in one of the fields and press submit many times to see the hash changing. It's working fine in the [demo page](https://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/), though.

What is going on?

Comment: You likely need to instantiate a new instance of the object each time. Calling update on the same object likely keeps the previous input around. (I'm guessing).   Additionally using SHA for passwords is not secure. Adding a salt helps but still isn't fool-proof. You should use bcrypt for passwords and you should do it server side.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! Do you know any other library that is more user friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsSHA's `.update()` method appends additional data after any previous updates, effectively concatenating them together:

```
shaObj.update(p.val());
shaObj.update(q.val());
```

```
// similar to...
shaObj.update(p.val() + q.val());
```

---

To calculate hashes for each input, you'll have to create a `new jsSHA()` instance for each:

```
var shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-512', 'TEXT'); // <---
shaObj.update(p.val());
var p_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
//p.val(p_hash);

var shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-512', 'TEXT'); // <---
shaObj.update(q.val());
var q_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
//q.val(q_hash);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that but didn't tried it... Do you know any other library that is more user friendly?

Comment: @ChazyChaz [Most hashing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/) will typically use 3 separate steps, [with `update` in the middle](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9193/). It's a common model that allows for working with chunked data, streams, etc.

Comment: I didn't know about those uses, and if it's common then I'll stick with it, thanks again.