# Similar Encrypt code in javascript as in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, hash, base64, sha256

I use some remote api, they use such C# code:

```
SHA256Managed sha256Managed = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] passwordSaltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("zda");

byte[] hash = sha256Managed.ComputeHash(passwordSaltBytes);

string result = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

Console.WriteLine("result = " + result); // result = NUbWRkT8QfzmDt/2kWaikNOZUXIDt7KKRghv0rTGIp4=
```

I need to get the same result in my javascript frontend code. Does somebody can help with such problem?

Comment: You might want to explore some Javascript libraries to achieve this easily. Check this post out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t

Comment: Not sure why you are hashing on the front end side though. Not safe right?

Comment: @theapologist i read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t and try to use some libe like js-sha256 and crypto-js but I could not find the right combination of actions to repeat the С# result, maybe you can help me =)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
var utf8arr = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse("zda");
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(utf8arr);
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
console.log(base64);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite obvious, but [Unicode in C# is using UTF-16LE enconding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

So you can use CryptoJS to achieve the same result:

```
var utf16 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse("zda");
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(utf16);
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
console.log(base64);
```