# How to import forge sha256 hash function on my Typescript Create React App project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, import

For reference, I am using React `16.9.0` and Typescript `3.5.3`.

On this question [Are there any SHA-256 javascript implementations that are generally considered trustworthy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t), I learned about the `forge` node application to create 256 hashes from strings.

Here, you can find the implementation and usage of the sha256 function:

1. https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/sha256.js
2. https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#sha256

However, I cannot manage to import it on my `create-react-app` project with Typescript.

I installed the [`forge`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) library with these commands:

```
npm install node-forge
npm install @types/node-forge
```

And when I try to import it, Typescript keeps telling me:

```
TypeScript error in /src/App.tsx(2,10):
Module '"node-forge"' has no exported member 'forge'.  TS2305

    1 | import React from 'react';
  > 2 | import { forge } from 'node-forge';
      |          ^
    3 | import './App.css';
    4 |
```

How can I correctly import the forge hash library in my [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) project, so I can create a hash with this:

```js
var md = forge.md.sha256.create();
md.update('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
console.log(md.digest().toHex());
// output: d7a8fbb307d7809469ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb762d02d0bf37c9e592
```

Comment: Have you tried `import * as forge from 'node-forge'`?

Comment: and what do you mean by "trustworthy"? If you mean "produces correct results", then you could test out a package by running it & checking the results against known values. If you mean something else, you should explain further.

Comment: @Kryten, I did not write `trustworthy`, who wrote `trustworthy` is the guy on the question I am linking.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `import forge from 'node-forge'` or `import * as forge from "node-forge";`
. Or you just use different library. For instance: `bcrypt`