# How can you create an app with html and js that works live on keypress?

Tags: javascript, html, hash

Im really stunned by what js combined with html can do. I recently searched on google for "sha256 online" and got a classic, type input and press button to get your output type of form.

Then when i searched for others, i found a page that requires absolutely no press of a button, but as soon as i type more letters in the box it was automatically/live hashing the input. How is this possible? And can i maybe implement such a design for my own application without any advanced skillsets(i am new to web development)?

https://quickhash.com/hash-sha256-online - this was the traditional styled type where a classic input button was required.

https://spacerival.com/Lounge/hashing-tools/ - on this one there is no key press needed, as soon as i type it updates?

I checked their html code and it's pretty much identical? I guess the magic is done on JS, but the js code is completely unreadable when i checked it :(

Comment: Yes, you can. There are tons of tutorials that will help you to implement `keypress` handlers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any SHA-256 javascript implementations that are generally considered trustworthy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t)

Comment: If you are asking HOW to do a live-updated "running checksum", the answer is hook into the "onchange" event of the field and use the "current" value.